# JSON experimental from Android App

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

On Android I am able to upload an object Ok.  But when I try to download it, I get the following error on getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out).

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type must be in the 'maintype/subtype; parameter=value' format
```

Code is from the Google example:

```
Storage.Objects.Get getObject = storage.objects().get("bucket", "myObject");
if (getMetadata == true) {
    getObject.setAlt("json");  // Temporary workaround.
    StorageObject object = getObject.execute();
} else {
    // Downloading data.
    out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // If you're not in AppEngine, download the whole thing in one request, if possible.
    // NOTE: As of right now, this will not retry on retryable failure.
    // http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=579
    getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(true);
    getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
    }
```

Comment: What version of the java library are you using? The latest is 1.15.0-rc https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/api-lib/java

Comment: I did not quite understand the Java API. Can you share the code snippet with which you uploaded your objects?