# upload image to google cloud storage with an application android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to google cloud storage.
I found an example like this https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage that explains how to do that.
I created a project bucket, etc., but when I try to create a client id
I get this error:

An error has occurred. Please retry later[image]

Where did this error come from?
Maybe there is another method to upload file to the google cloud storage with an  android application?

*******************************EDIT*******************************____________ in the new console I can see a message telling me only owner of the project can create clients for the application web and account services.
So error is caused because I connect with a account collaborator

[image]
*********************************EDIT*********************************__________
Now I can create client id, but I don't know how I can upload file from android to bucket, I read this https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage but it is for java not Android, anyone has an example how can I do that ?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Could you try to create the service account from the [new Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) clicking on your project -> APIs & auth -> Credentials -> Create new Client ID and inform us if you are able to do it in this way?

Comment: Hi, 

I just edit my first message

Comment: Hi @tamtoum1987, then this question could be considered as answered, right? All you need to do is ask a project owner either to give you owner permissions or to create a service account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can finally upload images on google storage like this

```
  class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
            scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);
              httpTransport= new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport();


              //agarro la key y la convierto en un file
              AssetManager am = getAssets();
              String STORAGE_SCOPE = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/" ;
              InputStream inputStream = am.open("*********114db0.p12"); //you should not put the key in assets in prod version.



              //convert key into class File. from inputstream to file. in an aux class.
              File file =stream2file(inputStream);


              //Google Credentianls
              GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                      .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                      .setServiceAccountId("**********ic1bgevf3h@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                      .setServiceAccountScopes((scopes))
                      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
                      .build();




              String URI = "https://storage.googleapis.com/" + "BUCKET_NAME"+"/"+"zzzzz3"+".jpg";
              HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(credential);


              GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(URI);




              //byte array holds the data, in this case the image i want to upload in bytes.

              Resources res = getResources();
              Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.camera);
              Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
              ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
              byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();


            HttpContent contentsend = new ByteArrayContent("image/jpeg", bitMapData );


              HttpRequest putRequest;

                putRequest = requestFactory.buildPutRequest(url, contentsend);




              com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse response = putRequest.execute();
              String content = response.parseAsString();
              Log.d("debug", "response is:"+response.getStatusCode());
              Log.d("debug", "response content is:"+content);
            } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return "";

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
        int i  = 0;
        int j = i;
        // TODO: check this.exception 
        // TODO: do something with the feed
    }
}
```

Don't forget to download jar and put it on lib folder:
 - com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jar
 - google-api-client-1.20.0.jar
 - google-api-services-storage-v1beta2-rev21-1.15.0-rc.jar
 - google-http-client-1.20.0.jar
 - google-http-client-jackson2-1.20.0.jar
 - google-http-client-jdo-1.20.0.jar
 - google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar

Comment: Hi can you tell me what is stream2file(),JSON_FACTORY,am.open("*********114db0.p12"),**********ic1bgevf3h@developer.gserviceaccount.com,

Comment: Sorry for the delay i juste saw your message, :(, 

stream2file:

  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  public static File stream2file(InputStream in) throws IOException {
   final File tempFile = File.createTempFile("okkk", null);
   tempFile.deleteOnExit();
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
   IOUtils.copy(in, out);

   return tempFile;
  }

Comment: Do you have those libraries as Gradle? I use Android studio

Comment: Sorry i used eclipse for this, 
doing a quick search i found this library for gradle : may be it helps you ? 

    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'

    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.20.0'

    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-admin-directory:directory_v1-rev53-1.20.0'

Comment: Sorry, but I am getting error as cannot found symbol StorageScopes and JSON_FACTORY. I have used following in gradle:  compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-admin-directory:directory_v1-rev53-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jdo:1.20.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client', version: '1.20.0'

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        try {
            List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();

            scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);
            HttpTransport httpTransport = new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport();

            //convert key into class File. from inputstream to file. in an aux class.
            File file =getTempPkc12File();


            //Google Credentianls
            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountId("xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx@xxxxx-xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
                    .setServiceAccountScopes((scopes))
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
                    .build();




            String URI = "https://storage.googleapis.com/" + GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET+"/images/"+createImageFile();
            HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(credential);


            GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(URI);




            //byte array holds the data, in this case the image i want to upload in bytes.

            Resources res = getResources();
            Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.camera);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();


            HttpContent contentsend = new ByteArrayContent("image/jpeg", bitMapData );


            HttpRequest putRequest;

            putRequest = requestFactory.buildPutRequest(url, contentsend);




            com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse response = putRequest.execute();
            String content = response.parseAsString();
            Log.i("debug", "response is:"+response.getStatusCode());
            Log.i("debug", "response content is:"+content);
        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("ErrorUpload",""+e.toString());
        }
        return "";

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
        int i  = 0;
        int j = i;
        // TODO: check this.exception
        // TODO: do something with the feed
        Log.i("OnPost",""+feed);
    }
}


private  File getTempPkc12File() throws IOException {
    // xxx.p12 export from google API console
    InputStream pkc12Stream = (NewProduceInfo.this).getResources().getAssets().open("xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx.p12");
    File tempPkc12File = File.createTempFile("temp_pkc12_file", "p12");
    OutputStream tempFileStream = new FileOutputStream(tempPkc12File);
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    while ((read = pkc12Stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        tempFileStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    return tempPkc12File;
}
```

1. Blockquote