# Access GoogleCloudStorage using GoogleCloudEndpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm working on this project in which I'm using a Google-App-Engine backend connected to an Android app via Google-Cloud-Endpoints. For Google-Cloud-Datastore access I'm using Objectify and everything works fine.

Now I decided to add the functionality to upload images to Google-Cloud-Storage but I couldn't find a clear explanation on how to do this using the Google-Cloud-Endpoints setup.

I found the following explanation how to use Google-Cloud-Storage with Google-App-Engine:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/app-engine-cloud-storage-sample

but  instead of adding it to the Endpoints Api the article writes an additional servlet.

Furthermore I found this example of upload/download for Android:

github.com   /thorrism/GoogleCloudExample

Sadly this is using the Google Cloud Storage API for direct access to the Google-Cloud-Storage and you need to add a P12-file to the asset folder, which seems unsecure.

My Google-App-Engine code looks like that:

```
@Api(
    name = "example",
    version = "v1", 
    scopes = { Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE }, 
    clientIds = { Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, Constants.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID }, 
    audiences = {Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE},
    description = "API for the Example Backend application."

)

public class ExampleApi{

@ApiMethod(name = "doSomething", path = "dosomething", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public String doSomething(@Named("text") String text){

  TestEntity test = new TestEntity(text);

   ofy().save().entity(test).now();

   return  test;
```

}

After I uploaded it I generated the Endpoints Client Library and imported it into my android project.

Then I'm calling Endpoints from Android like explained here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/calling-from-android#creating_the_service_object

```
public static com.appspot.******.example.Example buildServiceHandler(Context context, String email) {
    GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(
            context, AppConstants.AUDIENCE);
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(email);

     com.appspot.******.example.Example.Builder builder  = new  com.appspot.******.example.Example.Builder(
            AppConstants.HTTP_TRANSPORT,
            AppConstants.JSON_FACTORY, null);
    builder.setApplicationName("example-server");
    return builder.build();
}

sApiServiceHandler = buildServiceHandlerWithAuth(context,email);
```

And each Api-Method I call like this:

```
com.appspot.******.example.Example.DoSomething doSomething = sApiServiceHandler.doSomething(someString);
doSomething.execute();
```

All of this works fine, but only for storing/receiving Datastore Entities. How would I go about uploading/downloading files to Google Cloud Storage using the Google Cloud Endpoints setup?
Is it somehow possible to send a POST with my image data via Endpoints to the UploadServlet using the already build ServiceHandler ?
Is it possible to call a servlet from an Endpoints Method?  How am I supposed to send the Post to the Servlet and how would I go about the authentication?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853796/send-images-videos-from-android-ios-to-google-cloud-endpoints/40928219#40928219).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do this, but the most recommended way is to use [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), so that your Android app can upload the file securely to Google Cloud Storage directly, without going through your Endpoints backend. The basic process is:

1) Create an Endpoints method that [creates a new signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program) and returns it to the Android client. Signing the URL on the server still requires a P12 key but is stored on App Engine, not on the client, so is secure. Try to use a short expiration for the URL, for example no more than 5 minutes.

2) Have the Android client [upload the file directly to the signed URL](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), as you would doing a normal [HTTP PUT](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to the [Cloud Storage XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object) to upload a file ([resumable uploads with the JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable) are also supported, but not covered here).

Your Endpoints method might look like this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getUploadUrl", path = "getuploadurl", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
public MyApiResponse getUploadUrl(@Named("fileName") String fileName
                                  @Named("contentType" String contentType)
{
        String stringToSign
            = "PUT\n" + contentType
            + "\n" + EXPIRATION_TIMESTAMP_EPOCH_SECONDS + "\n"
            + YOUR_GCS_BUCKET + "/" + fileName;

        // Load P12 key
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_P12_KEY);
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(fileInputStream, password);
        PrivateKey key = keyStore.getKey(privatekey", YOUR_P12_KEY_PASSWORD);

        // Get signature
        Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signer.initSign(key);
        signer.update(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] rawSignature = signer.sign();
        String signature = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(rawSignature, false), "UTF-8");

        // Construct signed url
        String url
            = "http://storage.googleapis.com/" + YOUR_GCS_BUCKET + fileName
            + "?GoogleAccessId=" + P12_KEY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_ID
            + "&Expires=" + EXPIRATION_TIMESTAMP_EPOCH_SECONDS
            + "&Signature=" + URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8");

        // Endpoints doesn't let you return 'String' directly
        MyApiResponse response = new MyApiResponse();
        response.setString(url);
        return response;
}
```

On the Android side, you might use the method like this:

```
// Get the upload URL from the API
getUploadUrl = sApiServiceHandler.getUploadUrl(fileName, contentType);
MyApiResponse response = getUploadUrl.execute();
String uploadUrl = response.getString();

// Open connection to GCS
URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);

// Write file data
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpConnection.getOutputStream());
out.write(fileData);
out.flush();

// Get response, check status code etc.
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream());
// ...
```

(Disclaimer: I'm just typing code freely into a text editor but not actually testing it, but it should be enough to give you a general idea.)